# MySQL Update Trigger Error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an update trigger in MySQL Community Server 5.5.16 but I have got an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFER
ENCING NEW TABLE AS ntable
BEGIN atomic
        DECLARE n_overdraft INTEGER;
        DECL' at line 1
```

Could anyone help me with this problem. Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE overdraft(account_no INTEGER,over_draft INTEGER);

DELIMETER //
CREATE TRIGGER t_creditexceed AFTER UPDATE ON Account REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS ntable
BEGIN atomic
    DECLARE n_overdraft INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_balance INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_number INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_credit INTEGER;
    DECLARE credit_exception condition for SQLSTATE '07030';

    SELECT balance, credit, number INTO n_balance, n_credit, n_number
    FROM ntable;
    IF ((n_balance < (-n_credit)) AND (n_balance >= 1.1 * (-n_credit)))
    THEN
    SET n_overdraft = n_balance + n_credit;
    INSERT INTO overdraft (account_no, over_draft) VALUES (n_number, n_overdraft);
    END IF;
    IF (n_balance < 1.1 *(- n_credit))
    THEN signal credit_exception;
    END IF;
END;
//
```

Comment: DELIMETER -> DELIMITER. What is REFERENCING NEW TABLE?

Comment: It is reference to the "Account" table using transition table "ntable".

Comment: If you use MySQL, then this manual may be useful - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to delete `REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS ntable` and `atomic` because it's not MySQL Server standard.