# MySql triggers - referencing statement

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr1
AFTER DELETE ON Table1
REFERENCING
    OLD TABLE AS OldTable,
    NEW TABLE AS NewTable
FOR EACH STATEMENT
```

Produces the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCING 
OLD TABLE AS OldTable,
NEW TABLE AS NewTable
```

Why is this?

Comment: See [MySQL Update Trigger Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095519/mysql-update-trigger-error)

Comment: `REFERENCING` is not part of MySQL [`CREATE TRIGGER` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: So how can I reference the old table, i.e. its state, if I want to do something like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557205/mysql-trigger-for-keeping-min-number-of-rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view old table, then you should create BEFORE DELETE trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tr1
  BEFORE DELETE
  ON Table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  ...
  SET @old_count = NULL;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @old_count FROM Table1;
  ...
END
```