# MySql - trigger for keeping min number of rows

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to undo a delete statement if it brings the number of rows below 2000:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig1
AFTER DELETE ON Tab1

FOR EACH ROW
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) < 2000
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Table1 (select * from old);
   END;
END IF;
```

But it is not working. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, and how this should look?

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(*) Table1)` has no `FROM`

Comment: There is no "old" table on your database, as I know you have to manually specify the field for example old.ID, old.name, old.email etc. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * 
FROM   old
```

point to remember

- the number of tables and data types must match on both tables since you are using `*`

Comment: I don't get it, what is the difference between this and what I am already doing? What change should I actually make?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Table1 (select * from old);` is not a valid [`INSERT INTO...SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Another question, does old here refer to old table, or to old row? I would like to reference old table.

Comment: Nope, didn't work ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM old;

Comment: you're lacking `THEN`, try `IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) < 2000) THEN`

Comment: That at least compiles, let's see how it works. By the way, how would I refer to the old table, rather than the old row?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Trig1`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `Trig1`
AFTER DELETE ON Table1

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) < 2000 THEN
    INSERT INTO Table2(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(old.field1, old.field2, old.field3);
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I have actually tested it, and it works on my end.

Comment: After some research I found that on MySQL  it is not possible to update a table for for which the trigger is created in the trigger. My answer above will only work if you insert it to another table. It seems that you have to use transaction on DELETE operation on your UberUsers.

Answer (score 0):

You would fare better by creating a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger that raises an error (and thereby causes the statement to abort) if the operation would result in too few records:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER foo BEFORE DELETE ON Table1 FOR EACH ROW
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) <= 2000 THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
  MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot delete when table would result in too few records';
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) was only introduced in MySQL 5.5.  If using an earlier version, you must instead force MySQL to raise an exception by performing an erroneous operation; I often `CALL` a non-existent procedure with e.g. `CALL raise_error;`.